# Sikuli check two different images appear on screen

Tags: sikuli

I have been searching the net for a solution, but I did not find this specific problem. I need Sikuli to locate two images on screen simultaneously, and while that does not happen, perform an action:

```
while not ( exists (refSet.getImage("image1")) & exists(refSet.getImage("image2")) ):
        click(Pattern(refSet.getImage("image3")))
```

or

```
while not exists ( (refSet.getImage("image1")) & (refSet.getImage("image2")) ):
        click(Pattern(refSet.getImage("image3")))
```

I am getting an error:

*TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'org.sikuli.script.Match' and 'NoneType'*

Anybody knows how to solve this? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody needs it, I solved it creating my own function, but better ideas are appreciated!

```
def findTwoImages(self, image1, image2):
    bBoth = False
    imageCount = 0
    if exists(refSet.getImage(image1)): 
       imageCount += 1
    if exists(refSet.getImage(image2)):
       imageCount += 1
    if (imageCount == 2):
       bBoth = True 
    return bBoth
```

Comment: might be better to use boolean, and make two variables... if(first_image && second_image) both = true